# Store first element of ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im new to Angular..

I have a `ng-repeat` directive and I would like to store one of the `answer` attribute in a "global" variable.

I would like someting like this

```
var buffer = answer.discussionId;
<div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
    if(buffer != answer.discussion){
        //do something
        buffer = answer.discussionId;
    }    
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there will be a hack to do this. But you should never do this in angular. Do it in your controller!

Answer (score 1):

With angular the idea of doing conditional logic within your view is discouraged. You should really be doing any storing of data via your controller/model or through the use of directives.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly this will be the "angular way" to do this:

You need to create a `watch` to find when the value you spec has changed.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    "use strict";
    $scope.buffer ="";
    $scope.answers = [{ /*some object we do not know*/ }];

          $scope.$watch("answers",function(newValue, oldValue, scope){
                  var result =newValue.filter(function(answer){
                       return ($scope.buffer !== answer.discussion);
                  });
                  if (result.length > 0){
                      $scope.buffer = result[0].discussionId;
                  }
          },true);
}]);
```

For more information watch [click here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch)

Comment: im not sure this is what I need.. im gonna ask another question as Im trying to set my variable in the controller but can's access it in the html.. But thanks anyway.

Comment: variables must belong to $scope in order to be accessed.

Comment: I know.. this is my other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189154/http-and-scope-variable-not-showing-in-template