# $http and $scope variable not showing in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The variable `$scope.discussionId` is not showing in my template. Every other value are displaying

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT (Full Code)

**CONTROLLER**

```
soundshareApp.controller('CommentController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.data = { comments : [] }
    $scope.state = {}
    $scope.project = { id : [] }
    $scope.discussionId;
    $scope.test = "Hello World !";


    $scope.loadComments = function(userName, urlName){
        $http({
            url: '/comment/by_project_id',
            method: "GET",
            params:
            {
                username: userName,
                urlname: urlName
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.discussionId = data[0].discussionId;
            console.log("discussionId " + $scope.discussionId);//display the value !!
            $scope.data.comments = data;
        });;
    }
}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<div ng-controller="CommentController" >
    <div class='message-content' ng-click="state.show = !state.show">
        <img class='message-vignette' ng-src='{{commentData.avatarUrl}}'/>
        <div class='message-username'>{{commentData.username}}</div>
        <div class='project-message'> {{commentData.comment}}</div>
        <div class='message-date'>{{commentData.dateCreated | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma' }}</div>
    </div>

    <div  class="answer-message-content show-hide" ng-show="state.show" >
        <img class='message-vignette answer-message-vignette' ng-src='{{commentData.currentUserAvatarUrl}}'>
        <div class="add-comment-content">
            <form ng-submit="addComment(commentData)"   id="commentForm-{{commentData.projectId}}">
                <input id="input-comment-{{commentData.projectId}}" type="text" maxlength="255" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..." ng-model="commentData.msg">
                <input type="hidden" name="discussionId" value="{{commentData.discussionId}}" >
                <input type="hidden" name="projectId" value="{{commentData.projectId}}" >
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    test :  {{test}}// showing "Hello World!"
    discussionId: {{discussionId}}//not  showing !!
    <div ng-repeat="answer in answers" class="answer-message-content">
        <div class='message-content' ng-click="state.show = !state.show">
            <img class='message-vignette' ng-src='{{answer.avatarUrl}}'/>
            <div class='message-username'>{{answer.username}}</div>
            <div class='project-message'> {{answer.comment}}</div>
            <div class='message-date'>{{answer.dateCreated | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma' }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MAIN (Grails GSP)**

```
<div ng-init="loadComments('${params.username}', '${params.urlname}' )">
    <div ng-repeat="pdata in data.comments" >
        <div sdcomment param="pdata"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**DIRECTIVES**

```
soundshareApp.directive('sdcomment', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {
            commentData: '=param'
        },
        templateUrl: '/js/views/comment/templates/commentList.html',

        link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        }
    }

});
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you called $scope.loadComments?

Comment: Can you show your whole template code?

Comment: Yes ! all data are displaying except `discussionId`

Comment: What is data[0].discussionId coming back as? A jsFiddle would help us debug.

Comment: `data` is a JSON object. As I sayed the `console.log($scope.discussionId)`is displaying the value. A fiddle would be difficult as it is a Ajax request..

Comment: `$scope.data` is undefined. Therefore, `$scope.data.comments` will throws an error.

Comment: @beterraba ok I forgot to add it but he is in my code. Im updating it right now

Comment: this is associted with this initial question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21188062/1959948

Comment: If you need I can provide the whole template and the whole controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see `$scope.loadComments` gets ever called. `$scope.discussionId;` is initialize undefined. if you initialize it I bet you it will display that value, something like:

```
$scope.discussionId = 10;
```

Comment: loadComments is called  on another page, then I use directives to display my template

Comment: As I sayed `console.log($scope.discussionId)` display the value. And it is in the `success` function. All other value are displaying correctly.

Comment: Again you are missing the point... Think about this for a minute "your controller is initialize $scope.discussionId undefined".

Comment: i have removed it, then what yould I do..?

Comment: Yes "my controller is initialize $scope.discussionId undefined" then I set a value to it in the `loadComments success`function `$scope.discussionId = data[0].discussionId;` And at the same time `console.log($scope.discussionId)` is displaying the right value in the console.